# How to access a const value without defining a static Class in C#?

Tags: c#

In php I can define a Class with const value that can be easily accessed, how do I do that in C#?

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    const CONSTANT = 'constant value';
}

echo MyClass::CONSTANT;
```

The php class can be a general class, but has it to be a static Class in C# to get the same function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `const` variable by its very nature is a static value. That is why when you declare a constant in a class, you cannot declare a constant as `static` because it is already implicitly static.

```
public class Values
{
    public const int CONSTANT_VALUE = 12;
}
```

Accessing a constant is done the same way you access a static field.

```
int i = Values.CONSTANT_VALUE;
```

The limitation of `const`, however, is that it can only be used with built-in types whose values can be known at compile type (such as numeric types and strings, but not arrays). That's because when the program is compiled, the constant is actually turned into a literal value wherever it is referenced. After program is compiled, the above access to the constant gets essentially converted to this:

```
int i = 12;
```

Now just because a `const` field is implicitly static doesn't mean it can only be declared in a static class. A static class is just a specialized class that contains no instance members. A regular class can hold both static and instance members.

```
public class Values
{
    public const int CONSTANT_VALUE = 12;
    public int Val;
}
```

This class can be used as such:

```
Values v = new Values;
v.Val = Values.CONSTANT_VALUE;
```

Comment: thanks so much It solved my problem, I kept trying to access it using "::" instead of "."

Answer (score 1):

Just to correct a small mistake in @Abion47's answer...

The answer claims that "*The limitation of `const`, however, is that it can only be used with value types.*"

This is of course not true. Constants can be numbers, Boolean values, strings, or a null reference. Doing

```
public class Whatever
{
    public const string FooBar = "Hello World!";
}
```

is perfectly fine and works like a charm, despite `string` not being a value type. :-)